# How to edit entries in a flask table based on a hyperlink

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask, jinja2

new to coding and want to try having "editable" tables using a combo of pandas/flask/jinja.

I have a pandas dataframe that lists movies, years, and review scores, as well as whether a user has "watched" the movie or not. Below is an example of a table that has movies NOT YET watched:

[Table: movies not yet watched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWqEr.png)

However, the right-most column saying "Watched" does not work. How would I get it to work so that when a user clicks the "Watched" link, the pandas dataframe is updated and the movie in question is taken off the table?

Here is my code in `app.py`:

```
def index():
    """Show movies list"""

    # Access movies and TV dataframes
    df_movies = pd.read_csv('movies.csv', index_col=0, encoding='utf-8')

    # Query separate movies and tv databases based on username 
    user_id = str(session["user_id"]).replace('\[', '').replace('\]', '')
    movies = df_movies.loc[(df_movies["user_id"] == session["user_id"]) & (df_movies["watched"] == 'N') & (df_movies["mediatype"] == 'movie')].sample(frac=1) # Sample to randomise the list

    # Return table with updated values
    return render_template("index.html", len_movies=len(movies), len_tv=len(tv), movies_title=movies["title"].tolist(), movies_year=movies["year"].tolist(), movies_metascore=movies["metascore"].tolist(), movies_rtscore=movies["rtscore"].tolist(), movies_imdbscore=movies["imdbscore"].tolist()
```

And the code to render the table in html is thus:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left">Year</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left" style="width: 130px">Metacritic</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left" style="width: 130px">Rotten Tomatoes</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left" style="width: 130px">IMDb</th>
                <th scope="col" style="text-align:left" style="width: 30px"><img src="/static/favicon.ico" alt="" height="25"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <!-- Dynamically add rows -->
        {% for i in range(len_movies) %}
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left">{{ movies_title[i] }}</td>
                <td style="text-align:left">{{ movies_year[i] }}</td>
                <td style="text-align:left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/20/Metacritic.svg/120px-Metacritic.svg.png" alt="" height="25"><span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ movies_metascore[i] }}</span></td>
                <td style="text-align:left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d9/Rottentomatoesalternativelogo.svg/120px-Rottentomatoesalternativelogo.svg.png" alt="" height="25"><span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ movies_rtscore[i] }}</span></td>
                <td style="text-align:left"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/69/IMDB_Logo_2016.svg/125px-IMDB_Logo_2016.svg.png" alt="" width="40"><span class="badge badge-secondary">{{ movies_imdbscore[i] }}</span></td>
                <td style="text-align:left"><a href="">Watched!</a></td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Comment: first you have to use `<a href="some_url_with_movie_ID_as_argument">Watched!</a>` to send information to server, next server has to get this ID and use it to change values in pandas and save it in file.

Comment: BTW: you could send two columns as one data and later use `for movie in data` and `movie['title']`,  `movie['year']` instead of `for i in range(len_movies)`. And you should send also movie ID to use it in `href` for `Watched!` - ie. `href="/change/{{ movie_ID[i] }}`

Comment: @furas Thanks, your suggestion worked perfectly with a bit of my own personal tweaking. I ended using `href="{{ url_for('add_to_watch', id=movies_id[i])}}"` to be more jinja-esque, which routed to a flask function that had a route of  `@app.route("/add_to_watch/<int:id>")` and took argument `def add_to_watch(id)`